# Not authorized to access to rename, edit or delete on windows share

Tags: windows, windows-10, network-shares, shared-folders

I mapped the folder on a computer and sign in with the account (read and write).

Now I can read the folder and files but the problem is I can't rename and delete or even copy files/folders.

I try to use other credentials which is the "Administrator" but still I have same issue.

But on other computer I can edit everything.

**Screen shots for reference**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you only have share level permissions with the remote accounts and not any NTFS folder permissions greater than read. Grant the remote account modify permission from the security tab on the folder which is shared that you access remotely and that should resolve the problem—you only have read access at the moment with that account apparently.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I think I tried this one already. I even change the user to "Owner" and set Full control on the security tab and still can't modify files and folder.

And like I said I use admin credentials but still I can't modify the files/folder but when I use my admin on other system it's working

Comment: Ok I just tried only this user from domain credentials are not working.
I check the permission It's read and write.
I check the security and set to Full Control.
I even take ownership but still same issue

Comment: I updated my questions with screenshots. Said already set as owner and full control still I don't have access